# Show Ping Status in list in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ping

I am Using Asp.net mvc5, I have table with fields like "id", and "server_IP" populated with n-numbers of server ip. And wants to display the status of each IP " success" or "timeout" depending upon ping.

I have used  following;

```
Ping myPing = new Ping();
PingReply reply = myPing.Send("8.8.8.8", 1000);
if (reply != null)
{
ViewData["ip_stat"] = reply.Status;
}
```

I could not use this in my viewlist so that status of each servers can be shown as

Server                Status
8.8.8.8              Success
192.168.10.10        timeout 
192.168.100.1        sucess

REGARDS
ARUN SAHANI

Comment: can you show use how you access the viewdata in your view?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have understood your question correctly, but going by the kind of output you are looking for and the way your are initializing the viewstate, I think you should concatenate the ip and the status while passing it into viewstate.

Something like this:

```
ViewData["ip_stat"] = reply.Address + " " + reply.Status;
```

Hope it helps.

Edited for the case where addresses are fetched from some table and needed to be passed to viewstate

```
// suppose this variable has the list of IP addresses from the table
var addresses = new List<string> {"8.8.8.8", "192.168.10.10", "192.168.10.8"}

var ipStatusDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//iterate over the list, fetch the status for each ip and add it within the dictionary
foreach(var ip in addresses)
{
    var reply = new Ping().Send(ip, 1000);
    if (reply != null)
    {
        ipStatusDict.Add(reply.Address, reply.Status);
    } 
}

ViewData["ip_stat"] = ipStatusDict;
```

Comment: Its Ok, and output is as expected for the single data. I want to show this result for list of entire content of table containing the server IP,, and to show the ping status for each record.



            return View(db.RESOURCE_DETAIL.ToList());

Comment: Can u share the view code, how u are using this viewdata in there?

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {          
            Ping myPing = new Ping();
            string myip = 8.8.8.8; (here I want to load server IP from my table
            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(myip, 1000);
            if (reply != null)
            {
                ViewData["ip_stat"] = reply.Status;
            }

Note : using this viewdata in view page show for ip 8.8.8.8, but i want to use for the entire serverIP listed in tables       return View(db.RESOURCE_DETAIL.ToList());